# How to automatically switch my email signature in Outlook 365

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, email-signature

I have two email signatures. I use an internal signature for all `name@mycompany.com` recipients, and an external signature for all `name2@notmycompany.com`. At this moment, the default signature is the internal one. If I want to use the external one, I can manually set it in the ribbon.

I wondered if there was any possibility to let Outlook 365 automatically change the signature if he detects that the addressee email address does not belong to the company.

([Related question for Outlook 2007](https://superuser.com/questions/43602/can-i-use-a-different-signature-in-outlook-for-internal-versus-external-mail))

I tried to do this with a rule, but it seems that there is no suited rule available:
[image]

The 'Apply rule on messages I send' is only able to apply an action after the message has been sent (see following 2 images). But I would need it to be activated after I have entered the addressees.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What are your options when going to "Apply rule on messages I send" under the Start from a blank rule" section? (I just don't have a 365 account to test it myself.)

Comment: And BTW, the rules the guide I brought are not the Rules in the Outlook program, it should be in the online Exchange Control Panel.

Comment: @Yisroel Tech - Edited the question.

Comment: I see. But have you tried following my instructions using the online Exchange Control Panel?

Comment: @Yisroel Tech - No, I cannot find the online Exchange Control Panel in my online Office 365 / Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. You'll need to come up with some sort of custom solution or look for a third party app to help.  I looked around a bit and didn't really find any solution I would recommend.  Another route would be to look at smaller marketing integration tools - these may let you compose messages and send them with select signatures based on "campaign" - just assign certain users to the campaign and messages you generate will get the footer (or whatever else) you want to inject.

Back to a possible coding option

There is a forum string here that may help ( https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9cfedfdf-b7a8-442d-96b8-a5cf5a149673/adding-outlook-signature-using-ole-automation?forum=isvvba ).

They use the below to get access to signature files.

```
shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell"); 
user_name = shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%");  
fso =  new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
signatureTextStream = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\Documents and Settings\\" + user_name + "\\Application Data\\Microsoft\\Signatures\\" + user_name + "." + file_ext, 1);
signatureContents = signatureTextStream.ReadAll();
signatureTextStream.Close();
```

If you combine that with logic to read the recipients - you may be able to get a working solution for your self.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868695.aspx

```
Sub GetSMTPAddressForRecipients(mail As Outlook.MailItem) 
    Dim recips As Outlook.Recipients 
    Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient 
    Dim pa As Outlook.PropertyAccessor 
    Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS As String = _ 
        "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E" 
    Set recips = mail.Recipients 
    For Each recip In recips 
        Set pa = recip.PropertyAccessor 
        Debug.Print recip.name & " SMTP=" _ 
           & pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS) 
    Next 
End Sub
```

If I get some time - I will try and put this together in a working solution, but if anyone else were to post it for you that would be great too. Otherwise hopefully this get's you down the right path.

Comment: I accepted this answer as it is the most useful one, though I did not check it myself because I am now using an other system.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do so via Rules.

Here’s how to create a disclaimer that’s added to the bottom of all messages sent to external recipients (guide from [here](https://blogs.office.com/2012/06/04/add-signatures-and-disclaimers-to-your-email-with-office-365/)):

> 1. In the Exchange Control Panel, select Manage My Organization > Mail Control > Rules.
> 2. Click New. Enter the following information in the New Rule window:
> 3. Click “More Options…”
>
>    1. If…Select “The recipient…” and “is external/internal.” In the Select Scope window, select “Outside the organization,” and click OK.
>    2. Do the following: Select “Append a disclaimer to the message…” and “Append a disclaimer.”
> 4. Click “Enter text…” to enter the disclaimer text, and click OK.
> 5. Click Select one… to specify a fallback action that defines what you want to do if the disclaimer can’t be applied to the message. The
>      choices are “Wrap,” “Ignore,” and “Reject.” The default action is
>      “Wrap.”
>
>    1. To learn more about these options, see [Fallback actions](http://To%20learn%20more%20about%20these%20options,%20see%20Fallback%20actions.).
>    2. When you are finished, click OK.
> 6. To add exceptions to the rule so
>      the disclaimer isn’t applied to specific messages, click “Except
>      if…” For example, to specify specific users, select “The sender…”
>      and “Is this person” or “Is a member of this group.” For a complete
>      list of the available exceptions, see [Conditions and Exceptions for
>      Transport Rules](http://help.outlook.com/en-us/140/ff628740.aspx).
> 7. Name of rule: Accept the default name, or enter a unique, descriptive name for the rule.
> 8. Click Save.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if you're still looking for a solution, but I think that Crossware Mail Signature could help you out.

It acts as an add-on to Office 365 that applies your signature in the cloud each time you send out an email. You can easily create specific signature rules to have a different signature for internal and external users (and basically any rules you can think of). It has complete centralised management.

I hope that helps. Feel free to check it out here - http://www.crossware.co.nz/